# Magento 1.9 Import Product with CSV but with Dynamic Product names

Tags: magento-1.9, csv, product-import

I need to Import Product Using CSV 
But CSV does not have Product name column

so Need to create product names dynamic from products different attribute combination like type, color, fabric, etc.
if name is already exist need to re-order attribute combination and create new name.

i have values in csv like this for one product , its for  saree

- Supplier Name = some Supplier
- Design No(SKU) = 22389
- OCCASION = Party Wear
- STYLE = N/a
- Saree FABRIC = chiffon
- Blouse Fabric = Raw Silk
- TYPE = REGIONAL
- WORK = designer cut paste work, zari
- SAREE COLOR = pink
- BLOUSE COLOR =   pink
- TIME TO DISPATCHED = 3 Days
- SAREE LENGTH = 5.5 mtr
- BLOUSE LENGTH = 0.8mtr
- WEIGHT   = 1kg
- MRP  SELLING PRICE

so i need to use OCCASION, Saree FABRIC, TYPE, SAREE COLOR, WORK

please advise me how i can achieve this.

every help appreciated.

Comment: I think you should use product sku as product name.

Comment: in sku i have numeric numbers like 22460 , 22461
so it  not good to display numbers in Product name in front-side  and also for Seo

Comment: Is there any short description in your products ? If so, then we can try to make dynamic names using short description and attributes values.

Comment: i have update question with list on values i have